# node.js, MongoDB - async and await functionality not working as expected in findOne() function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I'm relatively new to node.js and MongoDB, so sorry in advance if it is an obvious answer.

I am trying to create the logic to validate an object that is being passed in, but I am having difficulty using async and await to time things correctly. Basically, I will be passing in a string and am trying to see if there is any record in the db that exists with that string. If there isn't, then `errors` returns empty, and if there is, then `errors` has something in it. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

The Schema (../models/FriendRequest):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var friendRequestSchema = new Schema({
    requestFrom: {type: String, required: true},
    requestTo: {type: String, required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('FriendRequest', friendRequestSchema);
```

The Logic:

```
var FriendRequest = require('../models/FriendRequest');

async function checkForDuplicateRecord(requestTo) {
    let errors = "";

    // do not allow duplicate requests
    FriendRequest.findOne({
        requestTo: requestTo
    }, (err, record) => {
        if (err) {
            errors += "{'\n'}Server Errors.";
        } else if (record) {
            errors += "{'\n'}You have already sent this person a friend request.";
        }
        console.log(record);
    })
    return await errors
}

// Function to perform server-side validation of the friend request before sending to db.
const FriendRequestValidator = (requestTo) => {
    let errors = "";
        (async() => {    
            let duplicationErrors = await checkForDuplicateRecord(requestFrom, requestTo);
            console.log('duplication errors: ' + duplicationErrors);
            errors += duplicationErrors;
        })()
    return errors;
};

module.exports = FriendRequestValidator;
```

When I print `record`, I see that if it exists, the data in `records` is correct. However, `duplicateErrors` is being printed before `record`, and is empty, even if `record` is not empty. This leads me to believe that the timing is the reason my results are not going as expected, and that I'm using `async` and `await` incorrectly.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Change function `checkForDuplicateRecord` in this way

```
async function checkForDuplicateRecord(requestTo) {
    let errors = "";
    try{
        // do not allow duplicate requests
        let record = await FriendRequest.findOne({
                requestTo: requestTo
            });
        if (record) {
            errors += "{'\n'}You have already sent this person a friend request.";
            console.log(record);
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        errors += "{'\n'}Server Errors.";
    }
    return errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`await` requires function to return the promise. But in your case you was calling the function and handling `errors` in callback function so you was getting `errors` as **empty string** in next statement.

```
async function checkForDuplicateRecord(requestTo) {
   let errors = "";
    try{
     let friendRequestSent = await FriendRequest.findOne({
        requestTo: requestTo
     });

     //If already sent request to same user throw error
     if(friendRequestSent)
        throw new Error("Your error message")

     //.... rest of code 

    }catch(err){
      //it will throw error if anything goes wrong in your findOne query or error thrown by your logic if request is sent to same user
      errors = err.message
    }
    return errors;
}
```